# Integrating Facebook Python SDK with Django

Tags: python, django, facebook

What is the most efficient way to integrate [Facebook Python SDK](https://github.com/facebook/python-sdk) with Django's authentication system? Or shouldn't I do this at all and create my own users models?

Basically, I'm using the Facebook JavaScript SDK for actually signing users on. Right now, when the JavaScript SDK creates the cookie, I'm using the Python SDK for getting the user's Profile Url, Access Token and other data (`facebook.get_user_from_cookie`), and after that I'm inserting it to the database using custom Django data models.

P.S: If there's any up-to-date app/middleware that does this automatically that'd be great :)

Thanks.

Comment: I did it the same as you.  Looked and tried all the common ones out there, but felt like none of them were truly complete.  Too many cases to account for, since the user's django session can expire, fb session can expire, django cookie can be deleted, fb cookie can be deleted, user can log out of fb while logged into your site, different user can log into fb while the first user is logged into your site and vice versa, etc.  If there is one app that handles all of these, please let me now!

Answer (score 2):

I've had good luck with the [django-socialregistration](https://github.com/flashingpumpkin/django-socialregistration) app.

Comment: I second that, it's very clean piece of code, doing its job perfectly.

Comment: For those of you using this: for Facebook, does it use the deprecated Facebook Connect API, or Facebook's recommended combination of the new JS Login button (JS SDK) for the client-side and django-facebook to read the cookie server-side?

Comment: It uses the new facebook graph API.